# Function works fine alone, but returns error with apply functions: attempt to select less than one element in get1index

Tags: r, function, error-handling, lapply

I have a list of character vectors that looks like this:

```
    [[1]]
    [1]   "medical"             "center"              "name
    [7] "laboratory"          "medicine"            "william"                 
    [13] "laboratories"        "2431"                "highway"             
    ...
    [680]

    ...

    [[100]]
    ..
    [590]
```

Each member of the list represents a patient and the character vectors per member are their tokenized medical reports. I'm mining each member of the list for certain parameters and am using the following code to do so:

```
    f <- function(x, phrase, n_words = 3L, upto = NULL) {
    x <- paste0(x, collapse = ' ')
    word <- '\\b\\w+\\b\\s*'
    p <- if (!is.null(upto))
            sprintf('(?:%s)\\s*((%s)+)%s|.', phrase, word, upto)
    else sprintf('(?:%s)\\s*((%s){1,%s})|.', phrase, word, n_words)
    trimws(gsub(p, '\\1', x))
   }
```

This function has worked great when using it on single character vector objects. For example:

```
    >f(P1, "histology results", upto = "diagnosed by"))
    [1] highly differentiated, stage 4 out of 4
```

Where P1 is a character object of tokenized words.

However, with lists and using the lapply function, I get an error.

```
   > lapply(list, f, list[[i]], "histology results", upto = "diagnosed by")
    Error in list[[i]] : 
         attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

When I run the function selecting the individual members of the list, it works fine for every member, with no errors thrown. Just as one example:

```
   > f(list[[2]], "histology results", upto = "diagnosed by")
   [1] "mildly differentiated stage 1 of 4"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice `i` substitutes for the index of the list in the individual case which works, e.g. `i=2`: `f(list[[2]], "histology results", upto = "diagnosed by")`

In your `lapply` function you are actually calling something akin to `list[[list]]` rather than `list[[1]], list[[2]], ..., list[[length(list)]]`.  Therefore the object you want to give `lapply` to iterate over is the list of indices `1:length(list)`. Try:

```
lapply(1:length(list), function(i) f(list[[i]], "histology results", upto = "diagnosed by"))
```

Or give the `list` object to `lapply` and call your `f` function directly on it without subset. Try:

```
lapply(list, function(i) f(i, "histology results", upto = "diagnosed by"))
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you! I still don't really understand the concept though. :-/

Comment: If you are familiar with for loops, this is similar to: `for (i in 1: length(list) { f(list[[i]], "histology results", upto = "diagnosed by") }`. How about you try these exercises and see what is returned `lapply(1:length(list), function(i) print(i))`, `lapply(1:length(list), function(i) list[[i]])`.

Comment: You can also try `lapply(list, function(i) print(i)`, then `lapply(list, function(i) f(i, "histology results", upto = "diagnosed by"))`